# how do i group a list of transaction by the date they are created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, mapreduce

```
 const transactions = [
  {
    date: "2021-04-16T08:52:24.408Z",
    type: "cash withdrawal",
    image: "",
    amount: "-5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z",
    type: "Cash Received",
    image: "",
    amount: "5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z",
    type: "Cash Received",
    image: "",
    amount: "5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z",
    type: "Cash Received",
    image: "",
    amount: "5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-03-17T20:30:00.000Z",
    type: "Cash Received",
    image: "",
    amount: "5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-02-01T20:30:00.000Z",
    type: "cashwithdraw",
    image: "",
    amount: "-5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-01-06T20:30:00.000Z",
    type: "cashwithdraw",
    image: "",
    amount: "-5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2020-08-06T19:30:00.000Z",
    type: "Cash Received",
    image: "",
    amount: "5000",
  },
];
```

given the above array of objects, i want to sort in such a way that all transaction create on let say january 10th is under january 10

this was what i was woring on but couldn't get it exactly and set it to be display cortly

```
let resp = transactions.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!acc[item.date])
    acc[item.date] = {
      date: item.date,
      data: [],
    };
  acc[item.date].data.push(item);
  console.log(acc?.data?.date);
  return acc
}, {});
```

this is what i am expecting to achieve[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6JFT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to address the date instead of taking the full date.

```js
const
    transactions = [{ date: "2021-04-16T08:52:24.408Z", type: "cash withdrawal", image: "", amount: "-5000" }, { date: "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z", type: "Cash Received", image: "", amount: "5000" }, { date: "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z", type: "Cash Received", image: "", amount: "5000" }, { date: "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z", type: "Cash Received", image: "", amount: "5000" }, { date: "2021-03-17T20:30:00.000Z", type: "Cash Received", image: "", amount: "5000" }, { date: "2021-02-01T20:30:00.000Z", type: "cashwithdraw", image: "", amount: "-5000" }, { date: "2021-01-06T20:30:00.000Z", type: "cashwithdraw", image: "", amount: "-5000" }, { date: "2020-08-06T19:30:00.000Z", type: "Cash Received", image: "", amount: "5000" }],
    result = transactions.reduce((acc, item) => {
        const date = item.date.slice(0, 10);
        (acc[date] ??= { date, data: [] }).data.push(item);
        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly how you want the final result, but this will work:

```js
const transactions = [
  {
    date: "2021-04-16T08:52:24.408Z",
    type: "cash withdrawal",
    image: "",
    amount: "-5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z",
    type: "Cash Received",
    image: "",
    amount: "5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z",
    type: "Cash Received",
    image: "",
    amount: "5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z",
    type: "Cash Received",
    image: "",
    amount: "5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-03-17T20:30:00.000Z",
    type: "Cash Received",
    image: "",
    amount: "5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-02-01T20:30:00.000Z",
    type: "cashwithdraw",
    image: "",
    amount: "-5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-01-06T20:30:00.000Z",
    type: "cashwithdraw",
    image: "",
    amount: "-5000",
  },
  {
    date: "2020-08-06T19:30:00.000Z",
    type: "Cash Received",
    image: "",
    amount: "5000",
  },
];

const res = transactions.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const date = item.date.split("T")[0];
  acc[date] ??= [];
  acc[date].push(item);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: thank you Chris Hamilton thank you for helping out. can you show how to display this in reactjs compnents